# How to count the number of fields in a database column? (excluding NULLS, not counting them)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Read the part below the image before criticizing, thanks. I would like to count how many fields there are in the ID_Campionato vertical column. In all there are 13, so I would like to get the result of 13. The table is called ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato, while the column ID_Campionato. I know that records and columns are the same, but I need them for a test, because the fields of the column are added separately later. If they don't align, some fields will have a NULL. So I would like to count the fields of the column excluding any NULLs from the count, to check that there are no problems.

[image]

**IMPORTANT**
I know, now you can tell me that I can simply count the rows of the records, but I reply that the data in the vertical column ID_Campionato is inserted later, inserted separately from everything else. So there could be an error because, by inserting them separately at a later time, they may not be the same with the number of records already present in the preceding. If they don't align, some fields will have a NULL. So I would like to count the fields of the column excluding any NULLs from the count, to check that there are no problems. That's why I want to check: I need it for some sort of test.The column ID_Campionato I add it later, after I have already created the records. I add it separately, because it is a column copied from another table. So I asked this question because I would like to do a test, to see if the fields of the ID_Campionato column have all been inserted correctly (since they are all inserted at a later time).

**UPDATE FOR HELP**

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()


    #Inserts all the Serie A teams all over again
    sqlite_insert_query_SerieA = 'INSERT INTO ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato (Nome_Squadra) VALUES (?);'
    cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_SerieA, Values_SerieA)
    count_squadre_SerieA = cursor.rowcount
    con.commit()      

    #Copy and insert, in the Teams table, the ID of the relative championship
    cursor.executescript("""
        UPDATE ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato
        
        SET ID_Campionato= (
            SELECT ID_Campionato
            FROM ARCHIVIO_Campionati
            WHERE Nome_Campionato = 'Serie A')
            
        WHERE ID_Campionato IS NULL;
        """)
```

Comment: In SQL, every record has the same number of column.  Are you asking "how many records have a non-null entry in the ID_Campionato column?"

Comment: A database column IS a field.  What are you trying to count exactly ?

Comment: I know what I'm asking. I know that each record has the same number of columns. If you re-read my question, I have written the reason for my question. The column ID_Campionato I add it later, after I have already created the records. I add it separately, because it is a column copied from another table. So I asked this question because I would like to do a test, to see if the fields of the ID_Campionato column have all been inserted correctly (since they are all inserted at a later time). Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You can certainly count how many records there are in the other table.  YOU are doing the merge, right?  After the merge, every record will have an ID_Campionato column.  If the merge didn't line up, then some of your records will have NULL in that column, and you can certainly count the NULLs.  Is that enough?

Comment: @Tim Roberts No, I did not merge. I copied them via UPDATE, SET (with SELECT, FROM, WHERE inside) and WHERE. I would like to count them precisely because as you said, if they do not align, some fields will have a NULL. So I would like to count the fields of the column excluding any NULLs from the count, to check that there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following exchange, done in SQLite3.  Is this what you're after?

```
DROP TABLE one;
DROP TABLE two;

.mode box

CREATE TABLE one (
  ID_Sq integer not null primary key,
  Nome_Squadra char(255),
  ID_Campionato integer
);

CREATE TABLE two (
  ID_Sq integer not null primary key,
  ID_Campionato integer
);

INSERT INTO one (ID_Sq, Nome_Squadra) VALUES
    (2865, 'Bologna'),
    (2866, 'Torino'),
    (2867, 'Udinese'),
    (2868, 'Sampdoria'),
    (2869, 'Venizia'),
    (2870, 'Spezia'),
    (2871, 'Genoa'),
    (2872, 'Salernitana'),
    (2873, 'Califari'),
    (2874, 'Pisa'),
    (2875, 'Benevento'),
    (2876, 'Reggina'),
    (2877, 'Brescia');


INSERT INTO two (ID_Sq, ID_Campionato) VALUES
    (2865, 1),
    (2866, 1),
    (2867, 1),
    (2868, 1),
    (2869, 1),
    (2870, 1),
    (2873, 1),
    (2874, 2),
    (2875, 2),
    (2876, 2),
    (2877, 2);

SELECT * FROM one;
┌───────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ ID_Sq │ Nome_Squadra │ ID_Campionato │
├───────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 2865  │ Bologna      │               │
│ 2866  │ Torino       │               │
│ 2867  │ Udinese      │               │
│ 2868  │ Sampdoria    │               │
│ 2869  │ Venizia      │               │
│ 2870  │ Spezia       │               │
│ 2871  │ Genoa        │               │
│ 2872  │ Salernitana  │               │
│ 2873  │ Califari     │               │
│ 2874  │ Pisa         │               │
│ 2875  │ Benevento    │               │
│ 2876  │ Reggina      │               │
│ 2877  │ Brescia      │               │
└───────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
SELECT * FROM two;
┌───────┬───────────────┐
│ ID_Sq │ ID_Campionato │
├───────┼───────────────┤
│ 2865  │ 1             │
│ 2866  │ 1             │
│ 2867  │ 1             │
│ 2868  │ 1             │
│ 2869  │ 1             │
│ 2870  │ 1             │
│ 2873  │ 1             │
│ 2874  │ 2             │
│ 2875  │ 2             │
│ 2876  │ 2             │
│ 2877  │ 2             │
└───────┴───────────────┘
UPDATE one SET ID_Campionato=two.ID_Campionato FROM two WHERE one.ID_Sq=two.ID_Sq;
SELECT * FROM one;
┌───────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ ID_Sq │ Nome_Squadra │ ID_Campionato │
├───────┼──────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 2865  │ Bologna      │ 1             │
│ 2866  │ Torino       │ 1             │
│ 2867  │ Udinese      │ 1             │
│ 2868  │ Sampdoria    │ 1             │
│ 2869  │ Venizia      │ 1             │
│ 2870  │ Spezia       │ 1             │
│ 2871  │ Genoa        │               │
│ 2872  │ Salernitana  │               │
│ 2873  │ Califari     │ 1             │
│ 2874  │ Pisa         │ 2             │
│ 2875  │ Benevento    │ 2             │
│ 2876  │ Reggina      │ 2             │
│ 2877  │ Brescia      │ 2             │
└───────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one WHERE ID_Campionato IS NOT NULL;
┌──────────┐
│ COUNT(*) │
├──────────┤
│ 11       │
└──────────┘
sqlite>
```

Which, of course, becomes:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one WHERE ID_Campionato IS NOT NULL;")
print(cursor.fetchOne()[0])
```

Comment: Exactly, I'm looking for this. SELECT COUNT (*) FROM one WHERE Championship_ID IS NOT NULL is just what I needed. Perhaps before I had explained myself a little bit wrongly in the question: I assumed that if there was a NULL it was not counted. For this we had misunderstood. Thanks a lot for the answer. If I wanted to print that 11, what should I write? Okay: count_column = SELECT COUNT (*) FROM one WHERE Championship_ID IS NOT NULL, and then print (count_column)?

Comment: From Python?  This is a query just like any other.  `cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM one WHERE Championship_ID IS NOT NULL;")`, then `row = cursor.fetchOne()` to fetch the data.

Comment: can you edit the answer, in order to complete it, show me how to write the code to print the result? I'm just starting out with python. Thank you

Comment: I need to see some of YOUR code, to see what kind of database and database connector your are using.

Comment: I see. I have updated my question, showing the code I use for the database. However, I specify that I only need to print "11". I already have the rest of the code you wrote (written a little differently). In this regard I would like to ask you (out of curiosity): what is the difference between your UPDATE one SET ID_Campionato = two.ID_Campionato FROM two WHERE one.ID_Sq = two.ID_Sq and my UPDATE / SET / FROM / WHERE? I notice that it is written different to you. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your answer is incomplete :) You wrote me the code for INSERT, UPDATE, SET, WHERE, but as I wrote I already had this code and I didn't need it. You have been very kind and I appreciate it, but what I needed was just the way to print the fields excluding Null, but you just wrote me SELECT COUNT (*) FROM one WHERE Championship_ID IS NOT NULL. Being new to Python, I don't know how to print. Can you show me please so I vote your answer and set it as a solved question? Thanks

Comment: Now, look here.  You did NOT say you knew how to count the null records.  You specifically said that was the piece you were missing.  Your title says that.  I supplied it.  I only included the other parts so that my answer was complete, including the sample data, which by the way I had to retype because you included an image instead of cut-and-paste data.  You did not even say you needed Python code.  If there is a shortcoming, it is in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry about this misunderstanding. I apologize. You're right. You have been very kind indeed. I have rated your answer and have set the question as resolved thanks to your answer. Thanks again and sorry